# Ajax try to update data from table but in other lines not work

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I update data information by an ajax on change in a table but just work with the first line, with the other lines did not work, this is my ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#table').on('change', 'input', function () {
        var test={
            "test1": $("#test1").val(),
            "test2":$("#test2").val()
        }
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url:    "data.php",
            data: alta,
            async:true,
            cache:false,
            success : function(response){
            if(response=="1"){
                alert("done");
            } 
            else{
                alert("sad");
            }
            },
            error : function(error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

How can I update the other lines in the table?

Comment: This code doesn't update anything. See [mcve]

Comment: Yeah I don’t put the update sentence but in that way the second line don’t execute the Ajax

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the rows with unique id or you need to user this keyword for get the particular row of data.

Comment: How can I obtaine the specific row?

Comment: Are you using datatable or simple table?

Comment: I use simple table

Comment: Please try this code  document.getElementById("table").rows[i].cells[j].innerText;